# how to cancel effects in yield all

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

in dva effect:

//useful; when next action come, the last action will be cancelled;

```
    getsome: [function*({ payload }, { call, put, select, all }){
      yield call request1;
      yield call request2;
    }, { type: 'takeLatest'}],
```

//but if use yield all, the last action will not be cancelled

```
    getsome: [function*({ payload }, { call, put, select, all }){
      yield all([call(request1), call(request2)]);
    }, { type: 'takeLatest'}],
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, You can't do it,

`yield all`,will start all the calls at same time,but not one after another.

So if you want to cancel the some of the requests you need to do it single, or make groups of yield, and init those one by by.